# Sub Workflow in Windows Workflow Foundation and Persistence

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I have a custom Activity that should call a sub workflow according to a name passed in an InArgument.

> public class CallSubWorkflowActivtiy : NativeActivity 
>   {
>
> ```
> public InArgument<String> SelectedWorkflow { get; set; }
>
> protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
> {
>    Activity subWorkflow = ActivityFactory.CreateActivity(SelectedWorkflow.Get(context));
>    context.ScheduleActivity(activity); 
> }
>
> protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
> {
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

My prefered solution would be to invoke the child activity with `context.ScheduleActivity`. That doesn't work because I can't add `metadata.AddImplementationChild(subWorkflow)` in `CacheMeta(context)` because i haven't access to the InArguments at this point.

A solution could be to hack around this an access the InArguments in the CacheMetadata. But this isn't a solution that should be implemented.

Another solution I came up with was to use the WorkflowInstance or WorkflowInvoker to execute the subWorkflow Activities.

> public class CallSubWorkflowActivtiy : NativeActivity {
>       public InArgument SelectedWorkflow { get; set; }
>
> ```
> protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
> {
>    Activity subWorkflow = ActivityFactory.CreateActivity(SelectedWorkflow.Get(context));
>    WorkflowApplication wfInstance = new WorkflowApplication(subWorkflow);
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

This solution would practically work. But I am not sure how the persistance is handled in this subworkflow an how the parent workflow continues when the child workflow finishes.

My questions are now:

1. Is there any way to call SubWorkflow Activities with context.ScheduleActivity(...) if the activity wasn't added practically with `metadata.AddImplementationChild(subWorkflow)`
2. If you use the WorkflowInstance class how is the persistance handled and how to continue the parent workflow if the child workflow finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

```
 protected override void CacheMetadataInternal(System.Activities.NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            InArgument<String> workflowVersionArgument = SelectedWorkflow;
            if (workflowVersionArgument != null && workflowVersionArgument.Expression != null)
            {
                String selectedWorkflowString = workflowVersionArgument.Expression.ToString();
                if (selectedWorkflowString != null)
                {
                    WorkflowVersion wfVersion = WorkflowVersion.LoadFromXML(selectedWorkflowString);
                    if (wfVersion != null && wfVersion.WorkflowName != null)
                    {
                        VersionedActivity subWorkflow = ActivityFactory.Instance.CreateActivity(wfVersion.WorkflowName, wfVersion.Version);
                        if (subWorkflow != null && subWorkflow.ActivityProp != null)
                        {
                            subWorkflowInternal = subWorkflow.ActivityProp;
                            metadata.AddImplementationChild(subWorkflowInternal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```